# Pandas - Filename in Path subfolder begins with number

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I am trying to write a dataframe to Excel to a path on my network drive, but one of the subfolders in the path begins with a number. In the error message, it appears the '2017' is being read as 'x817'.

Is there a workaround for this?

Example:

```
import os
export_path = 'C:\Users\Me\2017 Files\Data'
df.to_excel(os.path.join(export_path,r'Weekly Report.xlsx'))
```

Error Message:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\Me\\x817 Files\\Data\\Weekly Report.xlsx'
```

Thanks in advance!

Walt

Comment: Did you try making export_path a raw string too? `export_path = r'C:\Users\Me\2017 Files\Data'`

Comment: Try switching your forward slashes to backslashes. It worked for me. i.e. 'C:/Users/Me/2017 Files/Data'

Comment: Hi @ayhan that did the trick, thank you!